# how to specify query when searching for run in jenkins blueocean rest api

Tags: jenkins, api, jenkins-blueocean

I have some jenkins project, that has multiple pipelines defined. I can easily search for runs for a certain pipeline:

```
$ curl -k --silent "https://<SOME_SERVER>/blue/rest/search/?q=type:run;organization:jenkins;pipeline:<SOME_PIPELINE>;excludedFromFlattening:parameters" | jq '.[0]'
{
  "_class": "io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.PipelineRunImpl",
  "actions": [],
  "artifactsZipFile": null,
  "causeOfBlockage": null,
  "causes": [
    {
      "_class": "io.jenkins.blueocean.service.embedded.rest.AbstractRunImpl$BlueCauseImpl",
      "shortDescription": "<SOME_CAUSE>",
      "userId": null,
      "userName": "<SOME_USERNAME>"
    }
  ],
  "description": "<SOME_DESCRIPTION>",
  "durationInMillis": 0,
  "enQueueTime": "2023-03-15T18:40:05.356+0200",
  "endTime": null,
  "estimatedDurationInMillis": 2323462,
  "id": "3563",
  "name": null,
  "organization": "jenkins",
  "pipeline": "<SOME_PIPELINE>",
  "replayable": false,
  "runSummary": "?",
  "startTime": "2023-03-15T18:40:05.364+0200",
  "type": "WorkflowRun",
  "changeSet": [],
  "branch": null,
  "commitId": null,
  "commitUrl": null,
  "pullRequest": null
}
```

But is it possible to narrow the search even further? Best would be to search basing on jenkins job params. Currently only thing i can do is to process th json response with jq - which is not the best, as there are only basic fields returned by this API: